# Is this how you wrap dispatch in a Promise?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, es6-promise, dispatcher

So I have this piece of code that has a race condition:

```
    //load token from async and put it in redux's state
    AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then((data) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (data !== null) {
                store.dispatch({ type: t.LOGGED_IN, token: data });  //THIS
                this.setState({ isReady: true, isLoggedIn: true });  //RACING THIS
            }
            else {
                store.dispatch({ type: t.LOGGED_OUT });
                this.setState({ isReady: true, isLoggedIn: false })    
            }
        }, 5000)
    });
```

So I did some reading on how to wrap my dispatch in a promise so that only when dispatch is done I would call `setState` inside the promise's `.then`.

However, I couldn't really understand the use of a promise's `resolve` callback. Does it call whatevever I pass in `resolve` then when that's done it tells the promise object that it is resolved? Or is it saying that once the promise is resolve, run that piece of code? The former makes more sense to me so I did this to my code:

```
let promisedDispatch = (actionObj) => new Promise (function(resolve) { resolve(store.dispatch(actionObj)) });

    //load token from async and put it in redux's state
    AsyncStorage.getItem('token').then((data) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (data !== null) {
                promisedDispatch({ type: t.LOGGED_IN, token: data })
                    .then(()=>this.setState({ isReady: true, isLoggedIn: true }))
            }
            else {
                store.dispatch({ type: t.LOGGED_OUT });
                this.setState({ isReady: true, isLoggedIn: false })    
            }
        }, 5000)
    });
```

Now in this case, have I really solved my problem? 
I can't be sure because even before this modification the race condition REALLY rarely gives me any problem, since `dispatch` and `setState` takes roughly the same time so dispatch almost always finish first.

The only way to know for me is to confirm if `resolve(<x>)` is saying "hey try resolving  then let the promise know when it's done" or if my understanding is completely wrong.

Thanks in advance for the information! :)

Comment: no, because setTimeout has no concept of Promises - what you'll want if you want that 5 second delay, is to have a Promisified "delay"

Comment: by the way ... `new Promise (function(resolve) { resolve(store.dispatch(actionObj)) })` ... is basically `Promise.resolve(store.dispatch(actionObj))`

Comment: @JaromandaX but setTimeout is not the modification tho.. it is there for my splash screen so I can see it properly when I'm styling my splash screen. Thanks for the modification! that saves more space, but how would u propose I tackle this problem then if my promise is not doing what it's supposed to?

Comment: Why are you using `setState` with redux?

Comment: `but setTimeout is not the modification tho` - ok, so what does `store.dispatch(actionObj)` return? if it's not a Promise and it is asynchronous, then your code is still not waiting on it to complete - if it's synchronous, then why do you need to promisify it?

Comment: @MattWay no it's not in my reducer dw, it's just in my routes.js componentDidmount to know if I should still display the splash screen or not.

Comment: @JaromandaX yep that's what I feared, so that piece of code basically just run the `store.dispatch(actionObj)` on async and recognize it as resolved anyway yea? So how can I do this properly so that `setState` would wait for `store.dispatch()`?

Comment: but store.dispatch is synchronous according to documentation, so why are you claiming a race condition? how odd

Comment: PFFT I MUST'VE BEEN DREAMING! nvm then! thanks for the info, I was under the assumption that dispatch was async just like setState() because I didn't double check. It was giving me problem before, but maybe simply from my internet connection, because I'm running it on expo and expo doesn't complete the component that depends on another component unless there's connection to the same wifi as the computer I'm running `npm start` from

Comment: Ray, it looks like you're happy with your answer, but I notice you didn't talk about reducers and storing state in/fetching state from Redux (which is what @Matt Way was alluding to). If you remove your `.setState` and instead use a reducer to store `isReady` and `isLoggedIn` in your Redux store, then fetching it use `connect` it'll appear as a prop to this component and you won't have any timing issues.

Comment: @Rajit I can see why this snippet alone can be misleading, the timer there is not to solve anything it's just to let me see my splash screen whose rendering depends on the local `isReady` state. The whole point of this post was to address the 2 lines I marked in the first snippet, or so I thought until it was pointed out that they are not a problem at all. I was only under the assumption they were because of their behaviour prior to some other editing that fixed the problem. and this is NOT a snippet of my reducer, so `setState` is not an issue here, this is just my `routes.js`.

Comment: @Rajit I do use mapStateToProps in other components, but since this is my routes.js, if I use that here, everytime the props are updated due to dispatch in its own `componentDidMount` it will re-render the whole app and cause problems somewhere else with the async operations. And I do understand ur point of storing isReady and isLoggedIn in reducer, but those 2 are just used this one time in the app and only by this class so I don't wanna overcrowd my reducer for something so simple. Hope this clarifies the misunderstanding :)

Comment: Fair enough 